# My monitor is displaying text badly

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, hdmi, resolution

So, my monitor (Samsung Sync Master 932nw) has been working with no issue as usual, and all of a sudden, upong changing to another session on Windows 7 the text gets blurry, kinda wobbly in a strange way. I'll leave an image to demonstrate what I mean, although its not as clear in it as it is with the naked eye. I encountered other threads with the same issue I have, however their solutions didn't help me. I'm beggining to think it may be an issue with the monitor itself and I will have to replace it, but I'm trying to find a solution that will keep me from spending more money that I don't have. Here's what I tried to fix it:

[image: Image for reference.]

- Enabled/Disabled Clear Type and configured it several times.
- Changed to other resolutions (the problem persisted).
- Removed NVIDIA drivers completely and reinstalled them.
- Removed Windows graphic drivers and reinstalled them.
- Reverted to previous driver version.
- Fiddled around with all kinds of related configurations on NVIDIA Control Panel to no avail.
- Removed f.lux (program that applies a tint on the screen to make it easier on the eyes) in case it had something to do (did not).
- Changed refresh rate, which strangely changed how the image displays, although it should not.
- Fiddled with the monitor settings itself.
- Tried the auto-config present on my monitor several times.
- Changed colors.
- Changed between interlaced and progressive resolutions.

All this, and I got not a step closer to the solution. I will say, my monitor is kinda old. It outputs a 1440x900 resolution (16:10 ratio) at 60HZ (that's what I think at least, since setting it to 60HZ at the NVIDIA control panel screws up the display, so I need to keep it at 75). It also has only a VGA port, so I need to use a VGA to DVI adapter to hook it up to my GTX 750 TI.

I tried hooking up another TV/monitor I have lying around that has 1080p resolution and HDMI output. The drivers to the current monitor were already installed, so it didn't detect it as a new one. The software thought the new monitor I plugged in was the same as the other one and defaulted the resolution to 1440x900 even tho its 1080p. It displayed ok, the issue I'm describing was not present, and any attempt at getting the screen to 1080p resulted in a blurry image for some reason. I'm really all out of ideas at this point, I tried tons of different things, I removed and reinstalled all software related to display, I even unplugged my GPU, and nothing. I've had a dead pixel on this screen basically since I bought it and it looks as it always did, so the pixels itself should not be screwed up... I'm leaving the matter in your hands, please enlighten me.

Comment: Even if you have to borrow a monitor, you really need to test with a different display. Otherwise you'll spend a lot of time guessing without really knowing where the problem actually lies.

Comment: I mentioned in the post that I tried hooking up another display. I don't live alone in my house, and there's more than one computer here, that's where I got the other TV/monitor from. I tried with other displays, and although there's some incompatibility issues due to having the wrong drivers for them, the text seems to display ok, so the issue has to be my monitor, right? The thing is that I saw people with this issue having it resolved through software, not hardware, and it seems like such a strange issue for a display to have physically.(btw thanks for adding the image, won't let me bc rep)

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, if you don't see the exact same issue with another computer monitor you know it's your display.

Comment: Strange- I've seen similar issues on old CRT monitors when placed near a magnet or power transformer,  but I assume your's is LCD?

Comment: You assume right, Samsung's Sync Master 932nw if you're interested in the exact model.

Comment: The first thing I thought before even finishing your message was that this is VGA interference. VGA is an analog signal susceptible to interference and small electrical problems in the components in both your monitor and / or video card. You didn’t specify the model of your monitor? Anyways, monitors are pretty cheap. The act of changing the monitor and the signal type to DVI will surely fix the issue. I also notice you are running Windows vista. So needless to say all of this equipment appears beyond end of life.

Comment: No, I specified my monitor model on a comment, it's a Samsung's Sync Master 932nw. Yes, it has only a VGA output and I'm using an adapter to DVI so I can hook it up to my GPU. And no, I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Your screen shows the start menu of Windows Vista. The button is larger than the taskbar. That’s classic Vista style. On win 7 the start button fits entirely within the taskbar. So, while I believe you and I have no idea why you would be wrong, I’m curious why your image shows a Windows Vista style start button. Also, if you put relevant information, such as model, in your question instead of comments, you will be more likely to get the answers you’re looking for.

Comment: I added the model to the question. Regarding the look of the OS, I made some changes to male icons appear smaller, so the bar occupies less space, and the Windows logo is big enough to go out of the bar's bounds. Also, I replaced the tiny icons with the large bars once a program is open because it's easier to click on them that way. All of this can be done on stock Windows 7 (and 10) and it's just a preference.